# Is there any way to make X Mirror respect delete?

Tags: modeling, mesh, mirror

I find X Mirror (found in Tool Shelf> Options> Mesh Options) very useful, but it would be more useful if it would mirror my deleting vertices as well as morphing them.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

**Current solution**: Delete half the mesh, then apply mirror modifier, but when I have a bunch of bones and textures already in place, it's annoying to re-add them.

Answer (score 1):

I think Carlo's option makes sense, though it might need more explaining. The X- mirror splits down the center and mirrors in the negative X. Any changes you make in the negative, be that deleting or adding vertices will be updated in the positive X after you have applied symmetry. It does not work if you flip the process and work on the positive X first as the negative X will not be updated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Symmetrize function in edit mode (spacebar -> Symmetrize)

You will have to do this every time you want to synchronize one side to the other.

Comment: But that doesn't respect delete, it seems very similar to x mirror

Comment: maybe i'm going about this the wrong way, and should be trying to figure out a better way of mirroring bones, textures etc